# Why is pxd file file not found/seen while cythonizing?

Tags: python, cython, linker-errors, cythonize

I am trying to compile and run a Cython extension. There are three files in the same directory:

main.pxd

```py
cdef class Function:
    cdef object f
```

main.pyx

```py
cdef class Function:
    def __init__(Function self, object f):
        if callable(f):
            self.f = f
        elif type(f) in [staticmethod,classmethod]:
            self.f = f
        else:
            raise TypeError("constructor argument must be callable")
```

setup.py

```py
# import setuptools
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# define an extension that will be cythonized and compiled
ext = Extension(name="Do", sources=["main.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext,language_level=3))
```

I call `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. The code compiles without errors. However, when I try to create a new `Function` object in another Python module, I get the following error:

```
File "main.pyx", line 4, in Do.Function.__init__
AttributeError: 'Do.Function' object has no attribute 'f'
```

This tells me that the compiler is not aware of main.pxd. Adding `cimport main` to the top of main.pyx causes a compiler error.

How do I get Cython to see main.pxd, and include it in the binary?

Python 3.6, Cython 0.29.23, Windows 10

Update:

The Cython docs have [an example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html). In the Sharing Extension Types section there is code for a Shrubbery class. I copied the code exactly into main.pxd and main.pyx. I get a similar error as before: `'Do.Shrubbery' object has no attribute 'width'`.

Update:

Added `public` to cdef in pxd file. Same error occurs.

Comment: Try adding obvious nonsense to the pxd file - does that cause s compilation failure?

Comment: Obvious nonsense in the pxd does not affect compilation.

Comment: Extension name should be main and not Do in “ ext = Extension(name="Do", sources=["main.pyx"])”, the same as file name.

Comment: There must be a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by making the extension name the same as the names of the pyx and pxd files.